# one-to-many with Default

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have News. One news can have many Tags, Categories and Images. Special for it i thing about extended model.

```
public class NewsExt
    {
        public News News { get; set; }
        public List<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<Images> Images { get; set; }
        public List<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

or

```
public class NewsExt
    {
        public Base.News News { get; set; }
        public Categories Categories { get; set; }
        public Images Images { get; set; }
        public Tags Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

I work with second variant and want something like this:

```
    return
    ((from n in db.News
      from i in db.Images.DefaultIfEmpty()
      from t in db.Tags.DefaultIfEmpty()
      from c in db.Categories.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new NewsExt()
      {
          News = n,
          Images = i,
          Tags = t,
          Categories = c
      }).GroupBy(news => news.News))
```

I want *Array of NewsExt** with one News and all other entities without repeating in each element of this array.
For the **first viewmodel** I try:

```
(from n in db.News
          select new NewsExt()
          {
              News = n,
              Images = (from i in db.Images.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from n_i in db.News_Image
                        where n_i.news_id == n.id
                        select i).ToList(),

              Tags = (from t in db.Tags.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      from n_t in db.News_Tag
                      where n_t.news_id == n.id
                      select t).ToList(),

              Categories = (from c in db.Categories.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            from n_c in db.News_Category
                            where n_c.news_id == n.id
                            select c).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

But have excess records.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want - do you want a _single_ category or a list of categories?  It looks like you're trying to have a structure thatr can have either, which is not possible (you can have a list of categories with one entry, but that's not the same as having one and only one category)

Comment: I want a list of categories whicn have this news. News can have no one category.

Answer (score 0):

I decide to use **first viewmodel**.

```
(from n in db.News
 select new NewsExt()
 {
    News = n,
    Images = (from i in db.Images.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join n_i in db.News_Image on i.id equals n_i.image_id
              where n_i.news_id == n.id
              select i).ToList(),

     Tags = (from t in db.Tags.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join n_t in db.News_Tag on t.id equals n_t.tag_id
             where n_t.news_id == n.id
             select t).ToList(),

      Categories = (from c in db.Categories.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join n_c in db.News_Category on c.id equals n_c.category_id
                    where n_c.news_id == n.id
                    select c).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```